# Edit TextView with value from GPS

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a camera class that holds a picture of the camera using SurfaceHolder and so on. I enter the above SurfaceView TextView. and that I wanted to ask is how can I update the text in TextView with latitude and longitude values ​​I get from GPS?
where I put coding to get the current position and updates the position

Comment: you mean to say display current lat-long with photo ?

Comment: To expand on @Lucifer 's comment - are you somehow referring to [Geotagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the below changes to your code and try.

```
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewId);

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                String location = "Last known location\nLatitude = "+loc.getLatitude()+"\nLongitude = "+loc.getLongitude();
                textView.setText(location);
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "GPS Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();                
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "GPS Status Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();             
            }           
        });
```

In manifest file you have to use permissions as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
```

I hope you understand and it help you.

Answer (score 1):

use requireLocationUpdates from LocationManager.
commonly that process goes to background.

Answer (score 0):

im found the problem solving.. hehe

```
private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location){
      String latLongString;
      TextView longlati;
      longlati = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.longlati);
      if(location != null){
          double lat = location.getLatitude();
          double lng = location.getLongitude();
          latLongString = "Lat: " + lat + "\nLong: " + lng;
      }else{
          latLongString = "No Location found";
      }
      longlati.setText(" " + latLongString);

  }
```

sorry for my stupid questions. i just a bit stress >_<